# JavaScript TextEncoder / TextDecoder equivalent in python

Tags: javascript, python, arrays

I wanted to get the same results we got by using TextEncoder and TextDecoder on javascript but couldn't find real code solution the soluction I found doesn't give me the real same results.

exp:

```js
const textencoder = new TextEncoder();
console.log(textencoder.encode('$'));
//[36]

const textdecoder = TextDecoder();
console.log(textdecoder.decode(new Uint8Array([36]));
// $
```

Comment: in what specific context are you trying to use this? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: You really must provide *details*. At minimum, example inputs and corresponding desired outputs. What code did you try, and how was the output not correct?

Comment: giving an input to decoder like '$' and expecting a list like [36] and when we give it back to the decoder to get back the '$' that's all, at python the results I found about this didn't give me what I wanted I just missed using the casting to list and I think it something that need to be shared may someone need it someday, and thank you for your quick response

Comment: @WalidBousseta might want to add that context to your *question*. As of now the question itself is mostly useless.

Comment: I just shared this question to help someone that may need it in the future but since you guys voted down on it, I will be removing it sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

after a many tries and search, I got the solution form a friend and I decided to share it with you, may someone need it some day;

```py
class TextEncoder():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def encode(self, text):
        """
        exp:
            >>> textencoder = TextEncoder()
            >>> textencoder.encode('$')
            >>> [36]
        """
        if isinstance(text, str):
            encoded_text = text.encode('utf-8')
            byte_array = bytearray(encoded_text)
            return list(byte_array)
        else:
            raise TypeError(f'Expecting a str but got {type(text)}')

class TextDecoder():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def decode(self, array):
        """
        exp:
            >>> textdecoder = TextDecoder()
            >>> textdecoder.decode([36])
            >>> $
        """
        if isinstance(array, list):
            return bytearray(array).decode('utf-8')
        elif isinstance(array, bytearray):
            return array.decode('utf-8')
        else:
            raise TypeError(f'expecting a list or bytearray got: {type(array)}')
```